# Add several places to google through Google Places api at once

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add many places to google maps as custom places via google places api at once.

I read [this](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) article about how to add a place to google, but the client I am working with has thousands of places to add, so I was wondering if there is any other alternatives to add places to google?

Comment: Well, this [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) is the official way to add a place in the Google Maps. If you check the whole documentation of Google Maps API this the only option that you can use to add a place. When you add a place, the new place is available immediately in Nearby Searches initiated by your application. The new place also enters a moderation queue to be considered for Google Maps. But don't worry even though your location that you add is not accepted by the moderation process, you will still able to see this in your application.

Comment: Thanks Kendi! I read that document before, but it only allows us to add ONE place at once, I was wondering if there is any way by any chance that we can add MULTIPLE places to Google Maps. I don't mind if those places are qualified by Google since as you said, I can use them in nearby search anyway : )

Comment: sadly to say, that is the behavior of add place. You can only do it one by one

Comment: Thats good to know anyway, thanks!